# Use xpath to query multiple nodes for specific value

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have some XML and I need to query all `<USER>` nodes, specifically if the `<userID>` values are all the same. The node I want to check is userID. In the below example notice that the 2 `<userID>` values are different, so I would want the result of the XPath evaluation to be false.

Sample XML:

```
<xml>
<CHANGE_USER_001>
     <USER>
        <userID>joebloggs</userID>
     </USER>
</CHANGE_USER_001>
<CHANGE_USER_001>
     <USER>
        <userID>joebloggs1</userID>
     </USER>
</CHANGE_USER_001>
</xml>
```

My attempt at xpath command is

```
//USER/userID='joebloggs'
```

The query returns true but I would like to test against each `<userID>` node.

If returning a boolean is not possible then I could get the number of `<userID>` nodes, and then get the number of `<userID>` rows equal to my specific value, and then compare them, but how to check all `<userID>` nodes for the same value?

Comment: The question isn't clear! What do you mean by _if the values are all the same_? Which nodes do you want to query?

Comment: I want to query userID node and check if they are the same value

Comment: Can there be more than 2 users? Can the elements named CHANGE_USER_001 and CHANGE_USER_002 have different names?

Comment: Multiple users are possible, I just skimmed down the XML. XML node names will not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath,
`not(//userID != //userID)`

, returns `false` when at least one `userID` is different than any other `userID` in the whole document. It returns `true` when all the `userID`s are the same.

The `!=` operator returns `true` if the items on the right side of the expression have at least 1 value that doesn't match at least one of the items on the left side, else it returns `false`.

Comment: Very nice and concise!

Comment: Can I assign a boolean variable to the result ?

Comment: The result of this expression is always a boolean value.

Comment: Yes, but how to store that in a vb.net boolean variable?